# How to request permissions during run time when using Gluon mobile environment?

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, javafxports, gluon-mobile

I am new here and reason for that I don't know all rules of the site yet, sorry about that!

I am building a Java application to Desktop and Android by using Gluon mobile plugin in Eclipse tool. I have variated code for Desktop and Android as described in an example (http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/). So I have Android specific NativeService where I have a method to read files from external storage (that works). I have also studied how to request permissions on run time when using native Android environment ([Storage permission error in Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow) ). I am able to request the permission, but I can not catch the result.

I am now requesting the permissions same way, but how I can receive the results? I cannot overrrive onRequestPermissionsResult as in the example, becauce I have not directly available android.support.v4.app stuff. Could someone help me and provide an example?

## AndroidNativeService.java:

```
package com.tentaattorix;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.File;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.content.Context;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import com.avustajat.LueJaKirjoita;

/**
 * Sanaston luku: Android-natiivi toteutus!
 * @author PT
 * @version 24.10.2016
 *
 */
public class AndroidNativeService implements NativeService {

    private static final String TAG = "Tentaattorix Native Service";
    private Sanastot sanastot = new Sanastot();

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_USE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    public AndroidNativeService() {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public Sanastot haeSanastot(String juuriKansio, String sanastoRegex, char kommentti, char erotin) throws IOException {


        String polku = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        String readme = "LueMinut.txt";
        String kansioPolku ="";

        //Luodaan kansio, jos sitä ei vielä ole.
        File kansio = new File(polku, juuriKansio);
        kansio.mkdir();

        //Asetetaan oikeudet, jos vaikka auttais skannaukseen.
        kansio.setWritable(true);
        kansio.setReadable(true);
        kansio.setExecutable(true);
        kansioPolku = kansio.getAbsolutePath();


        //Kysy oikeudet, jos niitä ei ole!                                       
        if (isStoragePermissionGranted()) {

            //Luodaan kansioon tiedosto LueMinut.txt.
            try {
                LueJaKirjoita.luoLueMinut(kansioPolku, readme);
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                throw e;
            }

            //Informoidaan uudesta kansiosta ja sinne tulevista tiedostoista järjestelmää!
            scanFile(kansioPolku + File.separator + readme);


            //Luetaan sanastot kansiosta.
            sanastot = LueJaKirjoita.lueTiedostot(kansioPolku, sanastoRegex, kommentti, erotin);

        }

        // Jos sanastot ei sisällä yhtään sanastoa, 
        // niin laitetaan edes yksi :) 
        if (sanastot.annaLkm() < 1) {
            String[] rivix = {"Tyhjä sanasto!", "Empty glossary!"};
            Sanasto san = new Sanasto("sanasto_");
            san.lisaa(rivix);
            sanastot.lisaa(san);
        }
        return sanastot;
    }

    /**
     * //Informoidaan uudesta kansiosta ja sinne tulevista tiedostoista järjestelmää!
     * @param path lisätty polku+tiedosto
     */
    private void scanFile(String path) {

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationContext(),
                new String[] { path }, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Finished scanning " + path);
            }
        });
    }

    private  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (FXActivity.getInstance().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
                FXActivity.getInstance().requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_USE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For starters, you can add the `android-support-v4.jar` to your project:

Copy it from its location under ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar to a `libs` folder in your project, and then add the dependency to the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    androidCompile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

Assuming you are targeting Android SDK 23+:

```
    android {
        minSdkVersion '23'
        compileSdkVersion '23'
        targetSdkVersion '23'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
```

then you know that by default all the permissions included in the manifest will be disabled.

If you want to check for permissions on runtime, you can define a new activity that takes care of requesting permissions with a built-in dialog (using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`), register this activity in the manifest, and call it from the `FXActivity` within a new intent that passes a list with the required permissions.

You just need to call `FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler()` to listen to the end of that activity and resume the call if permissions were granted.

The following code is partly based in the [PermissionHelper class](https://github.com/mvglasow/satstat/blob/master/src/com/vonglasow/michael/satstat/utils/PermissionHelper.java).

I'll use the simple case of the Dialer service from the new Charm Down 3.0.0 [library](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down), that requires `Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE`.

*AndroidDialerService.java, under Android package*

```
public class AndroidDialerAskService implements DialerAskService {

    public static final String KEY_PERMISSIONS = "permissions";
    public static final String KEY_GRANT_RESULTS = "grantResults";
    public static final String KEY_REQUEST_CODE = "requestCode";

    @Override
    public void call(String number) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(FXActivity.getInstance(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler((requestCode, resultCode, data) -> {
                    if (requestCode == 11112) {
                        // if now we have permission, resume call
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(FXActivity.getInstance(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            call(number);
                        }
                    }
                });

                Intent permIntent = new Intent(FXActivity.getInstance(), PermissionRequestActivity.class);
                permIntent.putExtra(KEY_PERMISSIONS, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE});
                permIntent.putExtra(KEY_REQUEST_CODE, 11111);
                FXActivity.getInstance().startActivityForResult(permIntent, 11112);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (number != null && !number.isEmpty()) {
            Uri uriNumber = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
            Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uriNumber);
            FXActivity.getInstance().startActivity(dial);
        }
    }

    public static class PermissionRequestActivity extends Activity {
        private String[] permissions;
        private int requestCode;

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            FXActivity.getInstance().onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            permissions = this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(KEY_PERMISSIONS);
            requestCode = this.getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_REQUEST_CODE, 0);

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);
        }
    }
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
. . .
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
. . .
<activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" .../>
<activity android:name="com.gluonhq.charm.down.plugins.android.AndroidDialerService$PermissionRequestActivity" />
. . .
```

[image]

Comment: what does 11112  mean in  **AndroidDialerService.java**  ? @JosePereda

Comment: @guru_007 That's just a random `requestCode`, that is passed to `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`, to verify that  `setOnActivityResultHandler` is executed only for an Intent with that code.

Comment: Got it ! @ José Pereda!

Comment: `FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler((requestCode, resultCode, data) -> {
                //statement });`  is unavalible @Jose Pereda

Comment: @guru_007 What do you mean unavailable? Are you using a recent jfxmobile plugin?

Comment: `classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.5` is included ,when am using this `FXActivity.getInstance().setOnActivityResultHandler((request‌​Code, resultCode, data) -> { //statement });` my IDE prompts the error that this method unavailable.

Comment: Then it's an IDE issue. If you run  from command line `./gradlew android` it will work. On your IDE (Eclipse?) make sure you have added jfxdvk.jar as a dependency.